# instantiateInitialViewController(withIdentifier: String) does not exist?

Tags: ios, swift3

Here is a screenshot from Xcode 8.2:

[image]

If the function does not exist, how do you add identifier to a view controller these days?

Comment: It's `func instantiateViewController(withIdentifier identifier: String) -> UIViewController`. Note that the `initialViewController` don't need to have a identifier to be called (`func instantiateInitialViewController() -> UIViewController?`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use instead [`instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uistoryboard/1616214-instantiateviewcontroller) when you would like a `ViewController` and attach a view from the storyboard (UIStoryboard Id `Identifier`)

[`instantiateInitialViewController()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uistoryboard/1616213-instantiateinitialviewcontroller) is to instantiate the default view `initial`, this function takes **no argument** and is something you wouldn't usually do programmatically.

Comment: there's no argument to `func instantiateInitialViewController() ` use `instantiateViewController` instead

Answer (score 4):

```
let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "", bundle: Bundle.main)
sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "blue")
```

Comment: Swift 5: Cannot convert return expression of type 'UIStoryboard' to return type 'UIViewController' when I try to return